# Why is source info missing in flutter error

Tags: dart, flutter

I got the following error in the console while running my app:

```
flutter: type '() => Null' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => FutureOr<dynamic>' of 'f'
```

Unfortunately it doesn't tell me which code actually caused this error? Why is flutter missing some more information in the output?

```
Visual Studio Code 1.28.2
Flutter 0.9.4
Dart VM version: 2.0.0
```

Comment: Tried out dev and master channel, all with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't put any code, so as far as I can tell, you are using `()` which is returning Null, and you were supposed to use `(dynamic value)` returning `Future` in your method declaration somewhere in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately the code base is too bug for just a simple paste. ```flutter analyze``` returned  ```No issues found! (ran in 1.5s)```

Comment: No errors shown in the 'problem' view. I use Visual Studio Code, and errors seem normally to work. I added the version numbers in my post

Comment: The problem was a ```Future<void>```. I didn't know that by convention the caller has to use an unnamed parameter like ```(_) => ...```